# Is there a way to add a property to all items in a array through patch operation in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a document in CosmosDB with a structure like below. Property "items" is an array of object, I want to add a new property to each item in the array using cosmos sdk without specifying the index. Is there a feasible way of doing it.?

I tried to use Patch Operation but it expects index so want to know if there is any other way to do it.

Existing structure:

```
{
 "items": [
    {
      "prop1": "value"
    },
    {
      "prop1": "value"
    }
 ]
}
```

Expected Structure:

```
{
 "items": [
    {
      "prop1": "value",
      "prop2": "value"
    },
    {
      "prop1": "value",
      "prop2": "value"
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: You'll need to change the document's array yourself (by reading it into your app) and perform a "replace document" - there's no such patch operation to modify all elements in an array.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thanks for the response. If not patch operation, can you please suggest any other way to do it without looping through each object.?

Answer (score -1):

To support [David Makogon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272109/david-makogon) comment, through SDK we can update/add properties to all items in an array.

I used .net SDK EF core.
Here is sample code

1. Models

**Customer.cs**

```
public class Customer
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public string ContactTitle { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    }
```

**Item.cs**

```
public class Item
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
   }
```

When I used these models and save data to Cosmos Db account. Here is sample [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F34ab.png) for same.

Now I changed my Model *Item.cs*

```
public class Item
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    }
```

and used below code to update the items in array.

```
using (var context = new _DbContext())
{
var customer = await context.Customers.
            Where(e => e.CompanyName == "CompanyName1").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (customer != null)
        {
        customer.items.ForEach(q => q.Prop2 = "value2");
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

Here is updated [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx7ll.png).